# Format SharePoint's <properties> node as list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

SharePoint 2010's `listdata.srv` service returns an Atom feed for a given picklist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://apps/Requests/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schem as.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:etag="W/&quot;28&quot;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
...
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      ...
      <d:Name>Last, First</d:Name>
      <d:WorkEMail>first.last@domain</d:WorkEMail>
      ...
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

I would like to have quick way to display all of the nodes in the `/entry/content/properties` node in a list.

I've tried:

```
PS> Get-Url "http://apps/Requests/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List(1234)/Requestor" | Format-List -Property entry.content.properties
```

But this doesn't return a value.

This works, but I'd like to avoid the interim variable assignment step:

```
    [xml]$xml = Get-Url "http://apps/Requests/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List(1234)/Requestor"
    $xml.entry.content.properties
```

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? `([xml](Get-Url "...")).entry.content.properties`